# Using Python collections.namedtuple to make a DTO with a clean interface?

Tags: python, collections, dto

I'm new to Python from a Java background and I'm trying to construct DTOs to wrap my data [as I would with Java Collections framework](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/230747/is-it-a-good-practice-to-wrap-collection-in-java) by extending a collection.

```
public class MyDto<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements MyDtoInterface<T> { ... }
```

I've read [python-quick-and-dirty-datatypes-dto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933419/python-quick-and-dirty-datatypes-dto) and it seems to provide a basis for what I need.  However what I cannot figure from the accepted answers is how to make my dto a type rather than a wrapper.  The accepted answer is a python script rather than a class.  I want to avoid having to do this:

```
class NamedDto(namedtuple):
    data = namedtuple("first", "second", "etc")

dto = NamedDto()
dto.data.first = 1
dto.data.second = 2
dto.data.etc = None
print(dto)
```

and instead do this:

```
dto = NamedDto()
dto.first = 1
dto.second = 2
dto.etc = None
```

and/or

```
dto = NamedDto(1,2,3)
print(dto.first)
print(dto.second)
print(dto.etc)
```

I've also read, which don't seem to answer this specific question.

- [python collections.namedtuple() confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327263/python-collections-namedtuple-confusion)
- [Is it valid to make an extension of a collections.namedtuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817517/is-it-valid-to-make-an-extension-of-a-collections-namedtuple)

Comment: "However what I cannot figure from the accepted answers is how to make my dto a type rather than a wrapper. " i'm not sure what you mean here. It *is* a type.

Comment: Anyway, `namedtuple` objects are *tuples*, they do not support item assignment or attribute assignment like that. Also, you are not using the `namedtuple` type factory correctly. `class MyType(namedtuple)` doesn't work, `namedtuple` is not a class, it is a class factory, so you would need to call `namedtuple`, somnething like `namedtuple('MyBaseClass', 'arg1 arg2')` or else it will probably would throw a runtime error It *sounds* like you just want a class. Why are you even messing around with a `namedtuple` to begin with?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  yes namedtuple is a type but I want to create a type that extends namedtuple, not an instance of it as per the accepted answer.

Comment: No, `namedtuple` *returns* a type (i.e a class, a subclass of `tuple` to be precise). `namedtuple` is just a function, it is a class factory.

Comment: But why do you want to *extend* the built-in types? This is not a common python idiom at all. Generally, favor composition. Again, it sounds like you *just want a plain class*, what, exactly, does inheriting from some `tuple` subclass gain you?